# I'm trying to generate an array but the same id tags are breaking the html - javascript

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, json

I have been struggling with this all day. Before I learn how to make this dynamic I want to generate multiple divs with either difference id tags or classnames instead of ids. Whichever is easier. Currently I have an issue where my page spits out an array where each div has the same id. Please advise.

```
function byId(id) {
    return document.getElementById(id);
}

var txt = {
    "characters": [{
            "thumbn": "<img src=\"http:\/\/galnova.com\/nu_images\/tiled.jpg\"\/>",
            "fullName": "John Doe",
            "speci": "human male",
            "occup": "Web Personality",
            "cide": "Sleeper",
            "descr": "blah",
            "biog": "blarg",
            "allia": "chaos good",
            "fullon": "<img src=\"http:\/\/galnova.com\/nu_images\/ban_two.jpg\"\/>"
    },

    {
            "thumbn": "<img src=\"http://galnova.com/nu_images/tiled.jpg\"/>",
            "fullName": "Jane Doe",
            "speci": "human female",
            "occup": "Movie Producer",
            "cide": "Citric",
            "descr": "bluh",
            "biog": "blurg",
            "allia": "neutral",
            "fullon": "<img src=\"http:\/\/galnova.com\/nu_images\/tiled.jpg\"\/>"
    },

    {
            "thumbn": "<img src=\"http://galnova.com/nu_images/tiled.jpg\"/>",
            "fullName": "Canter Doma",
            "speci": "alienmale",
            "occup": "Chef",
            "cide": "Galv",
            "descr": "bleh",
            "biog": "blerg",
            "allia": "evil",
            "fullon": "<img src=\"http:\/\/galnova.com\/nu_images\/tiled.jpg\"\/>"
    }]
};

var obj = txt;
//obj.toString();
byId("thumb").innerHTML = obj.characters[0,1,2].thumbn;
byId("fname").innerHTML = obj.characters[0,1,2].fullName;
byId("spec").innerHTML = obj.characters[0,1,2].speci;
byId("occu").innerHTML = obj.characters[0,1,2].occup;
byId("cid").innerHTML = obj.characters[0,1,2].cide;
byId("desc").innerHTML = obj.characters[0,1,2].descr;
byId("bio").innerHTML = obj.characters[0,1,2].biog;
byId("alli").innerHTML = obj.characters[0,1,2].allia;
byId("char").innerHTML = obj.characters[0,1,2].fullon;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mn9LV/8/

Comment: Looked at the fiddle, I'm still a bit fuzzy on what the issue is / what you're trying to do.  I don't see any duplicate ids.  Are you trying to create multiple cards, one for each character, or are you trying to take the one card and replace its content w/ another character's stats, or something else?

Comment: I want all of the objects to generate in html not just the last on the array. I just realized where I messed up but I do not know how to fix it. The html is static I need to somehow generate that chunk everytime with a unique id for however many objects I have in my array!

Answer (score 0):

Your array doesn't work like that

The structure you have is `{[{},{},{}]}`, this means
`object { array [ object {}, object {}, object {} ] }`

What you wrote isn't simply possible using json and javascript

Instead try

```
// John Doe
byId("thumb").innerHTML = obj.characters[0].thumbn;
byId("fname").innerHTML = obj.characters[0].fullName;
byId("spec").innerHTML = obj.characters[0].speci;
byId("occu").innerHTML = obj.characters[0].occup;
byId("cid").innerHTML = obj.characters[0].cide;
byId("desc").innerHTML = obj.characters[0].descr;
byId("bio").innerHTML = obj.characters[0].biog;
byId("alli").innerHTML = obj.characters[0].allia;
byId("char").innerHTML = obj.characters[0].fullon;
```

Next is 1

```
// Jane Doe
byId("thumb").innerHTML = obj.characters[1].thumbn;
byId("fname").innerHTML = obj.characters[1].fullName;
byId("spec").innerHTML = obj.characters[1].speci;
byId("occu").innerHTML = obj.characters[1].occup;
byId("cid").innerHTML = obj.characters[1].cide;
byId("desc").innerHTML = obj.characters[1].descr;
byId("bio").innerHTML = obj.characters[1].biog;
byId("alli").innerHTML = obj.characters[1].allia;
byId("char").innerHTML = obj.characters[1].fullon;
```

**== Edit ==**

To better suit your needs based on commenting this may suffice

Enclose your object in a literal and build in the functions you need to filter or build html in the literal

```
var obj = {
    txt: {
        "characters": [{
            "thumbn": "<img src=\"http:\/\/galnova.com\/nu_images\/tiled.jpg\"\/>",
            "fullName": "John Doe",
            "speci": "human male",
            "occup": "Web Personality",
            "cide": "Sleeper",
            "descr": "blah",
            "biog": "blarg",
            "allia": "chaos good",
            "fullon": "<img src=\"http:\/\/galnova.com\/nu_images\/ban_two.jpg\"\/>"
        },

        {
            "thumbn": "<img src=\"http://galnova.com/nu_images/tiled.jpg\"/>",
            "fullName": "Jane Doe",
            "speci": "human female",
            "occup": "Movie Producer",
            "cide": "Citric",
            "descr": "bluh",
            "biog": "blurg",
            "allia": "neutral",
            "fullon": "<img src=\"http:\/\/galnova.com\/nu_images\/tiled.jpg\"\/>"
        },

        {
            "thumbn": "<img src=\"http://galnova.com/nu_images/tiled.jpg\"/>",
            "fullName": "Canter Doma",
            "speci": "alienmale",
            "occup": "Chef",
            "cide": "Galv",
            "descr": "bleh",
            "biog": "blerg",
            "allia": "evil",
            "fullon": "<img src=\"http:\/\/galnova.com\/nu_images\/tiled.jpg\"\/>"
        }]
    },
    byId: function(id) {
        return document.getElementById(id);
    },
    buildHtml: function(id) {
        this.byId("thumb").innerHTML = this.txt.characters[id].thumbn;
        this.byId("fname").innerHTML = this.txt.characters[id].fullName;
        this.byId("spec").innerHTML = this.txt.characters[id].speci;
        this.byId("occu").innerHTML = this.txt.characters[id].occup;
        this.byId("cid").innerHTML = this.txt.characters[id].cide;
        this.byId("desc").innerHTML = this.txt.characters[id].descr;
        this.byId("bio").innerHTML = this.txt.characters[id].biog;
        this.byId("alli").innerHTML = this.txt.characters[id].allia;
        this.byId("char").innerHTML = this.txt.characters[id].fullon;
    }
};
```

Usage

```
var objectById = obj.byId(0);
// Or build html
obj.buildHtml(1);
```

Comment: I really want to find a cleaner way to pass each through an array that is empty with the i++ thing but I am struggling with the terminology. I think one at a time displaying is fine...I just want to create a way where it can toggle through them.

Comment: can't I just scroll through each characters[] somehow?

Comment: See update with a literal instead, if you want to scroll through the characters use a for loop, you can use a foreach but that is EcmaScript5 and not always compatible with all browsers.

Comment: I just tried to implement this in jsfiddle and it broke. Any chance you could show me all the pieces actually working. If not I  understand.

Comment: Sorry, my byId function was bad, i've fixed that now. Thing you could try again?

Comment: Hmmm. This is what I just tried and it's not working :( http://jsfiddle.net/Cp7ac/

Comment: This works http://jsfiddle.net/Cp7ac/2/, you had added the //John Doe and //Jane Doe code in the literal which made it crash!

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure what you're trying to do, but at a quick glance, you probably aren't referencing the array of characters as you intended :

```
obj.characters[0,1,2].thumbn;
```

Will always give you the 3rd item in the array as your usage of the `,` (comma) operator in this case will always result in the value passed as `2`.

If you want item 1 , `obj.characters[0]`, item 2 `obj.characters[1]`, etc.

To expand, the the returned value of a series of commas in javascript will be the last evaluation. ie : `('a',1020,'dog')` will evaluate to 'dog'. `(10,20,30) == 30 // true`

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator